# Eloquent how to get count of a relation of a relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table of `ScheduledPrograms` each containing a number of `ScheduledProgramSegments`. Each `ScheduledProgramSegment` has many `registeredAttendees`.

I want to count the number of `registeredAttendee` for each `ScheduledProgramSegment` and use the largest as the count for `ScheduledProgram`

**Models**

`ScheduledProgram` one to many `ScheduledProgramSegments`

`ScheduledProgramSegments` many to many `registeredAttendees`

**Model Code**

```
Class ScheduledProgram extends Eloquent 
{
    public function registeredAttendees()
    {
       //how do I make something like the below work?    
       return $this->scheduledProgramSegments->attendees()->wherePivot('registered', 1);
    }


    public function getRegisteredCountAttribute() 
    {
         return $this->registeredAttendees->count();
    }

}
```

help!

Comment: Calling `$this->registeredAttendees()->count()` should give you the count of of number of attendees related to a ScheduledProgram

Comment: Doesn't work because `registeredAttendees()` doesn't work because I don't know how to make the eloquent relation inside work. <--how to do this is my problem.